# Saving Uint8array to a sqlite file

Tags: javascript, save

I am using [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) as an admin interface for a SQLITE3 database.

Basically sql.js provides an export method that returns a **Uint8Array** for the developer to further handle.

**Goal:** Have the user press a button and a "Save As" dialogue pops up to save a file that is a valid sqlite3 database.

**What I've tried:** This save code block I've found in various parts of the web researching this issue.

```
        /* Uint8Array */
        var binArray = db.export();

        var saveData = (function () {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            return function (data, fileName) {

                /* Is JSON.stringify necessary? */
                var json = JSON.stringify(data),

                    /* Is type: "octet/stream" correct? */
                    blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
                    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
        }());

        saveData(binArray, "sqldb.sql");
```

It properly saves a file called "sqldb.sql", but I get "Invalid file format" error from a database client software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The *type* should be the *MIME* `application/octet-stream` when you have binary data and no other *MIME* is more befitting
2. Calling `JSON.stringify` makes no sense, you end up with a *String* that looks like `'{"0":254, "1":128, ...}'` when you already have the binary data as you want to save it

Combining these two points, the function returned should look more like this

```
    // ...
        return function (data, fileName) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-stream"}),
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
```

You may also need to consider if the *Uint8Array* is really a complete `.sql` file in it's own right, i.e. if you did the call to get it not in a browser/ajax, but so it was written directly to disc (e.g. with curl or direct linked) would that file be a valid sql file?

Comment: Worked brilliantly with the MIME type. Thanks!